# Custom directive is not working/rendering the html on the browser

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a custom directive but when I try to render it on browser it is not working.Please see my code and guide me if you can see where I went wrong.

Below is my code

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('main',[]);
app.controller('servicecntr', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name='jagdish';
    $scope.changeclick= function(){
        $scope.name= $scope.name.split('').reverse().join('');
    }

})

app.directive('myDirectives', function(){
    return{
            restrict:'EA',
            scope:false,
            template: "<div> this is the print out of name {{name}}" + "onclick the modelPannel is <input type='text' ng-model='name'",
        }

})
```

Comment: Please provide your HTML code and explain what you are trying to achieve with the directive

Answer (score 0):

change the scope:true,you are inherited the scope from the parent controller, you are trying to  access the name from parent controller,and how you use this directive in html,i don't find that code.

Comment: Please provide a working example instead of explaining in theory, which will benefit others.

Comment: Go through the link you have an example.https://jsfiddle.net/shidhincr/eyNYw/4/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=eyNYw

Comment: Go through this link ,you get the clear idea on custom directives   http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/custom-directives.html\